# SOQL Not Finding Results Based On Territory2Id Filter

Tags: apex, soql, territory-management

I have a query looking for records whose Ids are in a set, and SF is acting like the IDs are not there, when all the debug logs show that they clearly are.

Here are the debug statements clearly showing that the set "TerritoryIDs" contains the value 0MI4P000000gIKvWAM.

[18]|DEBUG|Added Territory ID 0MI4P000000gIKvWAM to the list

[27]|DEBUG|TerritoryIds ={0MI4P000000gIKvWAM}

However, when the code runs, it never reaches the final debug statement, because the query returns no records. However, if I remove the line `WHERE Territory2Id IN :TerritoryIDs` from the query, it finds the records whose Territory2Id values ARE in TerritoryIDs!

Anyone else seen SOQL just stop working like this when it comes to the UserTerritory2Association object?

```
Set<Id> TerritoryIDs = new Set<Id>();

    for (UserTerritory2Association UTA : Trigger.new){


        if (UTA.IsActive){
            TerritoryIDs.add(UTA.Territory2Id);
                System.debug('Added Territory ID '+UTA.Territory2Id+' to the list');
        }
    }

    // find the Accounts for each Territory
    if (TerritoryIds.size() > 0){

        Set<Id> AcctIDsToUpdate = new Set<Id>();

            System.debug('TerritoryIds ='+TerritoryIds);        

        for (ObjectTerritory2Association OTA : [SELECT ID, ObjectId, Object.Name, Territory2Id                                               
                                                FROM ObjectTerritory2Association
                                                WHERE Territory2Id IN :TerritoryIDs
                                                ]){ 
            System.debug('Adding Account '+OTA.Object.Name+' to list of accounts to update');
            AcctIDsToUpdate.add(ota.ObjectId);
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify if/how you know that there are actually `ObjectTerritory2Association` records matching the filter.

Comment: If you look at the query, you can see it should return all OTAs where Territory2Id = 0MI4P000000gIKvWAM. This OTA does exist - if I remove the line "WHERE Territory2Id IN :TerritoryIDs" from the query, it returns the OTAs where Territory2Id = 0MI4P000000gIKvWAM.

Comment: `If a territory model is in Active state, any user can view that model, including its territories and assignment rules. For territories in an active model, any user can view assigned records and assigned users subject to your org’s sharing settings. Users cannot view territory models in other states (such as Planning or Archived).` -any of these apply?